# Create Date Ranges based on sum of record count (KQL, Azure Data Explorer, Kusto)

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

Given the below table, I would like to create an output that finds the maximum date ranges where the sum of 'RecordCount' is less than or equal to 20,000.  Also, If a single row is greater than 20,000 the resulting date range will be the start and end of that single day:

```
datatable(Date:string, RecordCount:long)
[
    "2022-04-24T00:00:00.0000000Z", 825, 
    "2022-04-25T00:00:00.0000000Z", 14925, 
    "2022-04-26T00:00:00.0000000Z", 18498, 
    "2022-04-27T00:00:00.0000000Z", 17558, 
    "2022-04-28T00:00:00.0000000Z", 15626, 
    "2022-04-29T00:00:00.0000000Z", 12755, 
    "2022-04-30T00:00:00.0000000Z", 2203, 
    "2022-05-01T00:00:00.0000000Z", 48594, 
    "2022-05-02T00:00:00.0000000Z", 4976, 
    "2022-05-03T00:00:00.0000000Z", 10835, 
    "2022-05-04T00:00:00.0000000Z", 27505, 
    "2022-05-05T00:00:00.0000000Z", 22808, 
    "2022-05-06T00:00:00.0000000Z", 23119, 
    "2022-05-07T00:00:00.0000000Z", 5141, 
    "2022-05-08T00:00:00.0000000Z", 2217, 
    "2022-05-09T00:00:00.0000000Z", 11334, 
    "2022-05-10T00:00:00.0000000Z", 58, 
]
```

Expected Result:

```
datatable(StartDate:datetime, EndDate:datetime, RecordCount:long)
[
    "2022-04-24T00:00:00.0000000Z", "2022-04-25T23:59:59.9999999Z", 15750, 
    "2022-04-26T00:00:00.0000000Z", "2022-04-26T23:59:59.9999999Z", 18498, 
    "2022-04-27T00:00:00.0000000Z", "2022-04-27T23:59:59.9999999Z", 17558, 
    "2022-04-28T00:00:00.0000000Z", "2022-04-28T23:59:59.9999999Z", 15626, 
    "2022-04-29T00:00:00.0000000Z", "2022-04-30T23:59:59.9999999Z", 14958, 
    "2022-05-01T00:00:00.0000000Z", "2022-05-01T23:59:59.9999999Z", 48594, 
    "2022-05-02T00:00:00.0000000Z", "2022-05-03T23:59:59.9999999Z", 15811, 
    "2022-05-04T00:00:00.0000000Z", "2022-05-04T23:59:59.9999999Z", 27505, 
    "2022-05-05T00:00:00.0000000Z", "2022-05-05T23:59:59.9999999Z", 22808, 
    "2022-05-06T00:00:00.0000000Z", "2022-05-06T23:59:59.9999999Z", 23119, 
    "2022-05-07T00:00:00.0000000Z", "2022-05-10T23:59:59.9999999Z", 18750, 
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [scan](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA42U306DMBTG73mKk11BBktbKBQMu1FfQL3SmKWDbmIGLKVkanx4C4r705pYuOHrL%20ecnq%20Hkiv9rHfCveFKZJ2SVbP14U4UrSyv275R2a5ttp7z5IBeM4IICVAUkOgBoWx8F%20h7Pc58YIT6cEFSK4mj1MLGdpZFKTPYxM4mlJoss7M0JrHBpnaW6MCXbIisLCEoPEdpgLAVjRhNI4MldjZNYgMN7dUiFlKDtXumD4ZM1u4aIQwxg7W7RkKMU4O1u0ZxhA3UbhohODHQPzzDYWg0F9s9Gy/Ns/MJ%20t4LCet3GAYCeFdorSt4A6UodlwKcHlRrLq%20HgcDckA%20bGXb71dVmVWNGhTPOVTqxXHHzJ0Se%20gwZKBkLyBfwk8A0OjJoMEcqs3G7fBi2p%20fbS%20BDMX6Q8Ij5I05jOVPJekcGv79%20m8O7QbyrhwPhtP3dc1l9SHgXnGpxr7kUFfN%20M/wfLhtyknkb5N4GjYfYrgnijc0eCpKp9jL9lUUKuAHftS/AJubNUScBAAA) operator

```
datatable(Date:string, RecordCount:long)
[
    "2022-04-24T00:00:00.0000000Z", 825, 
    "2022-04-25T00:00:00.0000000Z", 14925, 
    "2022-04-26T00:00:00.0000000Z", 18498, 
    "2022-04-27T00:00:00.0000000Z", 17558, 
    "2022-04-28T00:00:00.0000000Z", 15626, 
    "2022-04-29T00:00:00.0000000Z", 12755, 
    "2022-04-30T00:00:00.0000000Z", 2203, 
    "2022-05-01T00:00:00.0000000Z", 48594, 
    "2022-05-02T00:00:00.0000000Z", 4976, 
    "2022-05-03T00:00:00.0000000Z", 10835, 
    "2022-05-04T00:00:00.0000000Z", 27505, 
    "2022-05-05T00:00:00.0000000Z", 22808, 
    "2022-05-06T00:00:00.0000000Z", 23119, 
    "2022-05-07T00:00:00.0000000Z", 5141, 
    "2022-05-08T00:00:00.0000000Z", 2217, 
    "2022-05-09T00:00:00.0000000Z", 11334, 
    "2022-05-10T00:00:00.0000000Z", 58, 
]
| order by Date asc
| scan declare (acc_sum:long = 0, group_id:int = 0)
with
(
    step s1 : true => acc_sum  = RecordCount + iff(s1.acc_sum + RecordCount > 20000, 0, s1.acc_sum)
                     ,group_id = s1.group_id + iff(s1.acc_sum + RecordCount > 20000, 1, 0);
) 
| summarize StartDate = min(Date), EndDate = max(Date), RecordCount = sum(RecordCount) by group_id
| project-away group_id
```

| StartDate | EndDate | RecordCount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-24T00:00:00.0000000Z | 2022-04-25T00:00:00.0000000Z | 15750 |
| 2022-04-26T00:00:00.0000000Z | 2022-04-26T00:00:00.0000000Z | 18498 |
| 2022-04-27T00:00:00.0000000Z | 2022-04-27T00:00:00.0000000Z | 17558 |
| 2022-04-28T00:00:00.0000000Z | 2022-04-28T00:00:00.0000000Z | 15626 |
| 2022-04-29T00:00:00.0000000Z | 2022-04-30T00:00:00.0000000Z | 14958 |
| 2022-05-01T00:00:00.0000000Z | 2022-05-01T00:00:00.0000000Z | 48594 |
| 2022-05-02T00:00:00.0000000Z | 2022-05-03T00:00:00.0000000Z | 15811 |
| 2022-05-04T00:00:00.0000000Z | 2022-05-04T00:00:00.0000000Z | 27505 |
| 2022-05-05T00:00:00.0000000Z | 2022-05-05T00:00:00.0000000Z | 22808 |
| 2022-05-06T00:00:00.0000000Z | 2022-05-06T00:00:00.0000000Z | 23119 |
| 2022-05-07T00:00:00.0000000Z | 2022-05-10T00:00:00.0000000Z | 18750 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA42U306DMBTG73mKk11BBktbKBQMu1FfQL3SmKWDbmIGLKVkanx4C4r705pYuOHrL%20ecnq%20Hkiv9rHfCveFKZJ2SVbP14U4UrSyv275R2a5ttp7z5IBeM4IICVAUkOgBoWx8F%20h7Pc58YIT6cEFSK4mj1MLGdpZFKTPYxM4mlJoss7M0JrHBpnaW6MCXbIisLCEoPEdpgLAVjRhNI4MldjZNYgMN7dUiFlKDtXumD4ZM1u4aIQwxg7W7RkKMU4O1u0ZxhA3UbhohODHQPzzDYWg0F9s9Gy/Ns/MJ%20t4LCet3GAYCeFdorSt4A6UodlwKcHlRrLq%20HgcDckA%20bGXb71dVmVWNGhTPOVTqxXHHzJ0Se%20gwZKBkLyBfwk8A0OjJoMEcqs3G7fBi2p%20fbS%20BDMX6Q8Ij5I05jOVPJekcGv79%20m8O7QbyrhwPhtP3dc1l9SHgXnGpxr7kUFfN%20M/wfLhtyknkb5N4GjYfYrgnijc0eCpKp9jL9lUUKuAHftS/AJubNUScBAAA)

Comment: This is perfect... thank you!!!  I was unaware that this operator existed.  Makes sense since it is in preview.